# Test rxjs interval in Angular 6 component ngOnInit function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs

I have a component with the following ngOnInit function which polls a service method for status updates:

```
ngOnInit() {
  interval(2000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.dataService.getStatus())
  ).subscribe((result) => {
    this.uploadStatus = result;
  );
}
```

I am trying to test that the updates are actually happening using the following code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UploadComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});


it('should start checking for status updates', fakeAsync(() => {
  const dataService = TestBed.get(DataService);
  // Mock the getStatus function
  spyOn(dataService, 'getStatus').and.returnValue(Observable.create().pipe(map(() => 'woo')));
  // Should not be initialised yet
  expect(component.uploadStatus).toBeUndefined();
  tick(2000);
  expect(component.uploadStatus).toBe('woo');
}));
```

However `component.uploadStatus` is always null. How should I go about testing this type of scenario? Ideally I would like to check for multiple updates over time.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in the `beforeEach` of the unit test template the Angular CLI set up for you. You subscribe to the Observable created by `interval` during the first change detection cycle, i.e., in `ngOnInit`.

The subscription must take place inside the `fakeAsync` zone in order for `tick` to manage the Observable's time. Move the call to `fixture.detectChanges` inside the `fakeAsync` zone and you will see `tick` now manages the time.

```
beforeEach((): void => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UploadComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  // Get rid of call to detectChanges
});


it('should start checking for status updates', fakeAsync((): void => {
  // Arrange
  const dataService = TestBed.get(DataService);
  spyOn(dataService, 'getStatus').and.returnValue(of('woo'));
  
  // Assert
  expect(component.uploadStatus).toBeUndefined();

  // Act
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick(2000);

  // Assert
  expect(component.uploadStatus).toBe('woo');

  // Clean up RxJS.interval function
  discardPeriodicTasks();
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

What I eventually settled on was the following. I also had to store the subscription so that I can cancel it at the end of the test to prevent "periodic timers still in queue" errors:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Store the subscription so we can unsubscribe when testing
  this.pollingSubscription = interval(2000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.dataService.getStatus())
  ).subscribe((result) => {
    this.uploadStatus = result;
  });
}
```

Then test as follows:

```
it(`init`, fakeAsync(inject([DataService],
  (dataService: DataService) => {
    const testReturns = [
      of('woo'),
      of('yay')
    ];
    let currentReturn = -1;
    spyOn(dataService, 'getStatus').and.callFake(() => {
      currentReturn++;
      return testReturns[currentReturn];
    });

    expect(component.uploadStatus).toBeUndefined();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // expect(component.uploadStatus).toBe('Login');
    // spyOn(dataService, 'getStatus').and.returnValue(of('woo'));
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick(2000);
    expect(component.uploadStatus).toBe('woo');
    tick(2000);
    expect(component.uploadStatus).toBe('yay');

    // Unsubscribe to prevent the "periodic timers still in queue" errors
    component.pollingSubscription.unsubscribe();
})));
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to trigger change detection after tick, this should work

```
tick(2000);
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.uploadStatus).toBe('woo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `setTimeout()` to wait for 2 seconds (slightly more because you are again doing asynchronous task inside), and then check the `property` value.

Make sure to use `done()` method to notify the test runner that test case is completed.

```
it('should start checking for status updates', (done) => {
  const dataService = TestBed.get(DataService);
  // Mock the getStatus function
  spyOn(dataService, 'getStatus').and.returnValue(Observable.create().pipe(map(() => 'woo')));
  // Should not be initialised yet
  expect(component.uploadStatus).toBeUndefined();

  setTimeout(()=> {
        expect(component.uploadStatus).toBe('woo');
        done();
  },2500);

});
```